# How can I see if any values in one data frame exist in any other data frame?

Tags: r

I have eight data frames, all of which contain an `id` field and I want to know if any of the `id` values are common among all eight data frames.

I'm not looking for an intersection (where the values are common across **all** data frames); I simply want to know those instances where they appear in **any** of the other data frames.

Let's say that one of the data frames looks like this:

```
   id TestDay
1  66       m
2  90       t
3  71       w
4  59      th
5  38       f
6  84      sa
7  15      su
8  89       m
9  18       t
10 93       w
11 88      th
12 42       f
13 10      sa
14 33      su
15 49       m
16 51       t
17 80       w
18 32      th
19  1       f
20 91      sa
21 58      su
```

If you wish to create eight sample data frames, you can do so by using this code eight times (with different data frame names, naturally):

```
x <- data.frame(id = sample(1:100, 21, FALSE), TestDay = rep(c("m","t","w","th","f","sa","su"), 3))
```

I want to know if any of the `id` values listed here appear in any of the other seven data frames, and conversely, whether any of the `id` values listed in any of the other seven data frames exist in this one.

How can this be done?

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference for your problem, but the `id`s listed in your example are not unique.  That said, if you're looking for a bare-bones solution, you could simply use `dplyr::semi_join()` to filter your first `data.frame` by its `id`s that are present in the `dplyr::union()` of the other `data.frame`s.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right - the `id` values are in fact unique.  I'll update the question.  Good spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine all the dataframes in one dataframe with a unique id value which will distinguish each dataframe.

I created two dataframes here with `data` column representing the dataframe number.

```
library(dplyr)

x1 <- data.frame(id = round(runif(21, 1, 21)), TestDay = rep(c("m","t","w","th","f","sa","su"), 3))
x2 <- data.frame(id = round(runif(21, 1, 21)), TestDay = rep(c("m","t","w","th","f","sa","su"), 3))
combine_data <- bind_rows(x1, x2, .id = 'data')
```

group by the `id` column and count how many dataframes that id is present in.

```
combine_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(count_unique = n_distinct(data))
```

You can add `filter(count_unique > 1)` to the above chain to get `id`'s which are present in more than 1 dataframe.

Comment: I like this simple, clean approach the feature that @Zaw lists in their answer - where the data frame numbers are concatenated - is a very helpful feature for me. As such, I can't decide which answer to accept as elements of both provide me with the ultimate solution, so-to-speak.

Comment: You can select whichever is answer is most useful to you. To combine the dataframe numbers you can add `data = toString(unique(data)` in `summarise`.

Comment: Great, your addition is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Ronak 's answer, you can also concatenate `c()` the dataframe number using `summarise()`. This tells you which dataframe the ID comes from.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = letters[1:3])
df2 <- data.frame(id = letters[4:6])
df3 <- data.frame(id = letters[5:10])

library(tidyverse)
df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
       
df4 <- df %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "df_num") %>% 
  mutate(df_num = as.integer(df_num)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(
    df_found = list(c(df_num)),
    df_n = map_int(df_found, length)
  )

df4
```

[image]

Comment: I like this approach, although I like the feature from @Ronak's answer where he lists `filter(count_unique > 1)` as that is all I really need to focus on with this task; is that possible with your solution? I tried implementing it first in `summarise` and then adding the line at the end but it returned 0 results.

Comment: @Ronak's `count_unique` should correspond to `df_n`. So, you can just replace that in the `filter()` call.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) methods

1. Get the datasets in a `list` and rbind them with `rbindlist`
2. Grouped by 'id' get the count of unique 'data' with `uniqueN`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(x1, x2, idcol = 'data')[, .(count_unique = uniqueN(data)), by = id]
```